# Bash grep php error_log Fatal errors to file by filter

Tags: php, bash, error-log

I have webserver with several web applications running (PHP). The configuration is set up the way, that php error_log is deleted at midnight (so the file lasts for 24 hrs only).

The thing is, I would like to log all Fatal errors into another file or database but only for specific web applications. (there are about 20 running, 4 of them are mine).

I was thinking about creating a bash script, grepping the error_log file on "Fatal" and url of my applications, fetching the output to file and also remembering last line number of current error_log in separate cache file.

I would then put the script to cron and execute it every few minutes (starting at the last line of the previous run).

The whole idea is a little messed up and I think it could be written efficiently, any ideas?

Comment: `<?php ini_set("error_log", "/path/to/your/log/file");?>`

Comment: That would need to be inserted in every application, which is a bad practise.

Comment: It's a hell of a lot cleaner than this cron-based text processing you're trying to pull off. And I thought you only wanted it for a few apps. If you don't want it in your PHP code, put it in an `.htaccess` file. `php_value error_log "/path/to/your/log/file"` The setting is there for a reason, don't make your life complicated by trying not to use it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing a cron job seems OK if you can't configure this out of the box. I don't know PHP well enough. In java e.g. you can have the same log message go to several log files depending on criteria.

But I would have your cron job do both the collecting of the fatal errors AND the deletion of the "last day's" log file. This way you can suffice with a single run of this script, at midnight, and save yourself the complexity of knowing where you ended last time (and the chance you missed some errors that happened right before midnight). If the collection was OK, delete the old file, otherwise leave it for diagnosis and retry. It saves you a bunch (24*60) calls to the script.

Comment: The cronjob for deleting the file is set up by system administrators (unfortunately I cannot work with that).

Comment: then IMHO the easiest is to have your cronjob run one minute in advance of the delete-job, and handle the whole file at once, rather than working through the file every few minutes looking for a 'restart-point' each time. Again, you'll loose the last minute of fatal errors but there no way around that anyways if you can't interfere with the delete job.

Comment: The problem is that I need to see the errors happen almost in real-time. That's why I decided that cronjob will be fired every few minutes.

Comment: have you considered `tail -f` ?

Comment: well that could be done, but the tail ends everyday since the file is deleted daily.

Brings up a question to just tail -f error_log to specific file and refresh it daily with cronjob.

Comment: yes that's what I mean. You can handle the tailed output instead of the real file, and use cron to "re-tail" every night. As a bonus, if you run the script at the same time as the delete script (and wait for it to create the new file), you won't even have the issue of possibly losing fatal messages that happen right before midnight, since your tail is certain to have seen everything.